# Inferring type information from memory read size

Tags: intel, intel-pin

I am using PIN to instrument my application binary and generating a list of addresses (more specifically memory reads) made by the application. I have an instrumentation routine, which passes the IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE, IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA as arguments. However,I want to infer the type information of the application variable based on memory size being read.

For example, 
           If PIN observes a memory read of 4 bytes, how can I conclude what type of data is being accessed. Is it int/float ? Similarly, for 8 byte data, how would I know if the data is a double variable or a pointer type variable.

Comment: You'd need to know the instruction used, not just the size and memory address.  Typical compiler output will use `movsd` / `movss` for FP loads, and `mov` for integer loads (into gp regs) or `movd` / `movq` (into vector regs).  Loads can also be memory operands to ALU ops.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Thanks for the answer.I seem to get movss for FP loads only when I compile with -O1/2/3 flags.Regular compilation seems to generate mov A, dword <..>  only.What could be the reason for this? You can remove this as comment and post as an answer. I will accept it :)

Comment: Can you post an example?  I don't think gcc should use `mov eax, dword [mem]` to load a float, even if it's just storing it again right away without doing any FP math.  Type or copy a function into http://gcc.godbolt.org/, and click "permalink".  My comment isn't a proper answer to the question, since you still can't distinguish `int64_t` from a pointer.  And some compilers will copy structs around with wide loads/stores that span multiple narrower members (like `int`.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can infer the type of the operand just by its size. I even doubt you can do it in a reliable manner with the instruction.